# Node.js, Express Routes, async and callback/building a result object

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, request, npm

I've hit another brick wall where I can't quite grasp what to do here, or at least how to do it the correct way. I've implemented an async call so I can run multiple requests in a waterfall method and each one relies on the result of another. This works fine, the trouble is, the third step in the waterfall actually needs to make multiple requests.

What I have at the minute is like below:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        Object.find().exec(function (err, records) {
            callback(null, records);
        });
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        request('url' + arg1.property + '', function(err, resp, body) {
            callback(null, arg1, JSON.parse(body));
        });
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        var array = {newarray:[]};

        arg2.forEach(function(eachField){
            request('url' + arg2.property, function(err, resp, body) {
                array.newarray.push(JSON.parse(body));
            });
        });

        // AT THIS POINT THIS ARRAY SHOWS AS EMPTY
        console.log(array);

        callback(null, arg1, arg2, array);
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // RESULT BREAKS DUE TO FORMAT OF DIFFERENT RESPONSES
    console.log(result);
});
```

This is kind of working. It makes the first request, sends the data to the second function in the waterfall, makes 10 further requests etc.

Firstly, the array I'm pushing everything to appears empty outside of the 'request' call, and secondly the format of data that comes back from each request is different - this second part I can sort out, but basically I need to understand how to make a request, off the back of that request make 10 further (small, honest!) requests and build these into an object.

At the end I essentially want to end up with something like:

{
    response1: dataSet,
    response2: dataSet,
    response3: dataset
}

And in the future, I may want to add or change some of these, so any help would be hugely helpful!!! All I'm trying to do is make a few requests, build an object with their JSON responses so in my view I can do what I want with that large amount of data!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's zoom in on that third step because the rest of your code seems to work. The problem is that the `array.newarray.push(...)` is in a callback function, which will be called once a response to the request has come in. Node doesn't wait for that to happen, it just makes the requests in the loop, console.logs your array (which is still empty at that time) then calls the callback which starts the next step. Then at some later point the responses come in, your callbacks get executed and properties get pushed to that array, but by that time it is too late.

So, what needs to happen here is that we need to wait for all the requests to come back and then call the callback to go to the next step. You can use async for this task to, but the [map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) operation this time. Using it, we could rewrite the step like this:

```
function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    var sendRequest = function(eachField, requestCallback) {
        //This function will be called for each element of arg2.
        request('url' + arg2.property, requestCallback);
    };

    async.map(arg2, sendRequest, function(err, responseArray) {
        //responseArray contains the responses to all your requests.
        callback(null, arg1, arg2, array);
    });
}
```

Note that this code still contains some errors I took over from your code (for instance, `arg2.property` is always the same, so you're making many identical requests).

So what happens here? I created a separate function that makes the actual request for a certain field. `async.map()` calls that function once for every element of `arg2`. It waits until each `sendRequest()` calls its callback with a result. Then it calls the function passed as its third argument and passes it all those results in an array. Once you have your results, you can can call the next step of your `async.waterfall()`.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I'm really busy so won't be able to take the time to try your example above for a week or two, but when I do I'll be sure to come back and vote/accept the answer :). Looks great and makes complete sense though.